# How to make use of reference to a variable in c#

Tags: c#

I would like to shorten the expression like

```
this.GdkWindow.GetPosition(ConfigurationService.ApplicationSettings.rect1.X,
                           ConfigurationService.ApplicationSettings.rect1.Y);
```

to something like `this.GdkWindow.GetPosition(refRect1.X, refRect1.Y)` using reference to a `ConfigurationService.ApplicationSettings.rect1` variable.

In C++ I am able to make use of a reference to the object (or variable) like this:

```
Rect& refRect1 = very.very2.very3.long_variable.rect1;
GetPosition(refRect1.x, refRect1.y);
```

How can I make the same in C#?

And how can I make a reference to the `int` variable like the following C++ code does:

```
int A = 5;
int& B = A;
B = 12;
```

**Update:** The `GetPosition` method is declared as `void GetPosition(out int x, out int y)`. That method fills the `ConfigurationService.ApplicationSettings.rect1` struct with some data. That's why i would like to use a reference.

I know I can do something like:

```
    var rect = new Gdk.Rectangle();
    this.GdkWindow.GetPosition(out rect.X, out rect.Y);
    this.GdkWindow.GetSize(out rect.Width, out rect.Height);
    ConfigurationService.ApplicationSettings.rect1 = rect;
```

but is there a way to avoid using the temporary variable? Is C# missing a feature even PHP has? Absolutely disappointed in C#!

Comment: if you want to create reference to int, you don't think managed. Even if there is the `ref` keyword, forgot what you learn with c++ (except all OOP stuff minus multi inheritance)

Comment: I just want to shorten the code. Are there any ways to make a short name alias to `ConfigurationService.ApplicationSettings.rect1` struct?

Comment: Why do you even want a reference to it? Just put the thing itself in a variable..

Comment: @harold, I have updated the question. I'd like to avoid using a temporary variable.

Comment: @ezpresso, you can't use property as input for `out` parameter. You _MUST_ use temporary variable in your case.

Comment: @Tomislav, The `ConfigurationService.ApplicationSettings.rect1` is a public field, not a property.

Comment: That's a public field of type struct. You have the pass the `out` keyword anyway. `Rect r; GetPosition(out r.X, out r.Y); ConfigurationService.ApplicationSettings.rect1 = r;`

Answer (score 6):

This should works, assuming the type of `rect1` is `Rect` (`var` keyword is not liked but everybody) :

```
Rect r = ConfigurationService.ApplicationSettings.rect1;
this.GdkWindow.GetPosition(r.X,
                           r.Y);
```

Actually, this will create a copy of the struct, but should we care ? As you only want to read field, a copy can be used.

(note I'm not sure if it's a copy)

Comment: If it's a struct, it's a copy.

Answer (score 3):

Those are all nested properties, so you can't shorten them, unless you store them in a variable first. With regards to long namespaces, you can do something like

```
using System.Data.Long.Namespace.Here.SqlClient = SQLALIAS;
```

And then use it like `SQLALIAS.ClassName`.
As for the second question, to use pointers in .NET you need to use them in `unsafe` context and build your project with option "Allow unsafe code" checked, although I'm not sure how this works or even if it will compile under Mono, which I assume you are using due to `GdkWindow`.

```
unsafe
{
    int A = 5;
    int* B = &A;
}
```

**Follow up to your Update:**

You have to call GetPosition like this.

```
int x, y;
GetPosition(out x, out y);
```

As the compiler says `A property, indexer or dynamic member access may not be passed as an out or ref parameter`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a way around using a temporary variable because every time you access ConfigurationService.ApplicationSettings.rect1 a copy of the Rect object is made.

If Rect.X and Rect.Y are public *fields* you can do this:

```
Rect r;
this.GdkWindow.GetPosition(out r.X, out r.Y);
ConfigurationService.ApplicationSettings.rect1 = r;
```

If they are *properties* you will need:

```
int x, y;
this.GdkWindow.GetPosition(out x, out y);
ConfigurationService.ApplicationSettings.rect1 = new Rect(x, y);
```